# Send a message in a channel "only visible to you"

Tags: slack-api

I can not see in the slack API documentation the way for a bot to send a message in a channel that response to a user.

The same way `slackbot` does reply when doing `/help`.

Anyone can let me know if that is possible?

[image]

Notice the "Only visible to you". In the RTM manual they say that the messsage is of the same type as the event [message](https://api.slack.com/events/message).  I don't see any attributes that would say it is visible only to a certain user.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sending private messages in channels with the "Only visible to you" tag is called "ephemeral" and is now possible through the Slack API.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral

(I'm not sure since when)

Comment: Please note: Ephemeral message delivery is not guaranteed — the user must be currently active in Slack and a member of the specified channel. By nature, ephemeral messages do not persist across reloads, desktop and mobile apps, or sessions.